# Format long number to shorter version in Lua

Tags: regex, lua, lua-patterns

I'm trying to figure out how I would go about formatting a large number to the shorter version by appending 'k' or 'm' using Lua. Example:

```
17478    => 17.5k
2832     => 2.8k
1548034  => 1.55m
```

I would like to have the rounding in there as well as per the example. I'm not very good at Regex, so I'm not sure where I would begin. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Lua native pattern matching isn't regex. Further more, this doesn't look like a pattern matching problem. What's the possible range of these number? You know that `17.5k` is not a valid number in Lua, right? Show what you have tried and specify the problem more clearly.

Comment: The numbers coming in will be raw, as shown on the left in my example. The largest possible number I would expect would be in the millions. I want to take the raw number and format it to the versions I have shown on the right.

Comment: There seems to be some inconsistency in the number of digits in the results. How are you determining that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pattern matching doesn't seem like the right direction for this problem.

Assuming 2 digits after decimal point are kept in the shorter version, try:

```
function foo(n)
    if n >= 10^6 then
        return string.format("%.2fm", n / 10^6)
    elseif n >= 10^3 then
        return string.format("%.2fk", n / 10^3)
    else
        return tostring(n)
    end
end
```

Test:

```
print(foo(17478))
print(foo(2832))
print(foo(1548034))
```

Output:

```
17.48k
2.83k
1.55m
```

Comment: Perfect! The only thing I changed was the %.2f to %.1f for the "k" version, since I only want one digit after the decimal place for numbers of that size. Guess I was overthinking it that I thought I would need Regex. Thanks alot!

Comment: No need to use string concatenation. Add the suffix to the format string.

Comment: I think it's a little more complicated than that (although, the question still doesn't say what the rounding rules are). `foo(9.9999e5)=="999.99k"` but "1.00m" would seem more desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Here a longer form, which uses the hint from Tom Blodget.
Maybe its not the perfect form, but its a little more specific.
For Lua 5.0, replace ***#steps*** with ***table.getn(steps)***.

```
function shortnumberstring(number)
    local steps = {
        {1,""},
        {1e3,"k"},
        {1e6,"m"},
        {1e9,"g"},
        {1e12,"t"},
    }
    for _,b in ipairs(steps) do
        if b[1] <= number+1 then
            steps.use = _
        end
    end
    local result = string.format("%.1f", number / steps[steps.use][1])
    if tonumber(result) >= 1e3 and steps.use < #steps then
        steps.use = steps.use + 1
        result = string.format("%.1f", tonumber(result) / 1e3)
    end
    --result = string.sub(result,0,string.sub(result,-1) == "0" and -3 or -1) -- Remove .0 (just if it is zero!)
    return result .. steps[steps.use][2]
end



print(shortnumberstring(100))
print(shortnumberstring(200))
print(shortnumberstring(999))
print(shortnumberstring(1234567))
print(shortnumberstring(999999))
print(shortnumberstring(9999999))
print(shortnumberstring(1345123))
```

Result:

```
> dofile"test.lua"
100.0
200.0
1.0k
1.2m
1.0m
10.0m
1.3m
>
```

And if you want to get rid of the "XX.0", uncomment the line before the return.
Then our result is:

```
> dofile"test.lua"
100
200
1k
1.2m
1m
10m
1.3m
>
```